# Audio anomaly identification

Tags: acoustics, weight, biology

I left an audio recorder in the forest in many different locations for fauna identification. I am collecting subjects on my audio recorder that are clearly not in the frequency range of any animal collected so far. An average 35 kg wallaby hopping has a high frequency range of between 2000 and 13000 Hz. The unknown subjects have a frequency range of between 46 and 100 Hz; very heavy.

I've done a drop test of a 10 kg dumbbell onto the forest floor at 5 different heights and at 1-50 metres. 250 drops collected on audio for comparison. At a height of 1 metre, the 10 kg dumbbell bounces off the forest floor 14 mm. Apparently this is an impact of 700 newtons but I've been told that this is inaccurate without taking into account the elasticity of both forest floor and dumbbell.

How can I accurately determine distance and weight of the unknown subject without spending money on impact plates or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Is this interpretation correct? You want to figure out what produces a 46 to 100 Hz frequency sound. You're modeling animal's stepping/hopping noises as a falling object. You want to know how high and what the mass of the assumed falling object are?

Comment: I rather doubt there's a monotonic relationship between weight and frequencies, or even between weight and amplitude.  Different animals have radically different stride patterns.  It's like the difference between a child jumping with a "stomp" and a ballerina landing noiselessly.

Comment: Thanks very much for the comments !BMS , exactly , I want to know what the distance and weight of the unknown subjects are by establishing a known weight/frequency/distance  baseline  .
Carl , I totally agree , there will be multiple gaits and strides from multiple animals but surely a 35kg wallaby cant make an impact like a 300kg deer .